# Is -makeWindowControllers the best place to initialize an NSPersistentDocument?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspersistentdocument

When loading an existing document using `NSPersistentDocument`, as part of initialization I'd like to prepare some content:

```
    NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DocumentRoot"];
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:NULL];
    if (results.count) self._docRoot = [results objectAtIndex:0];
```

When I put this code in `-init`, the fetch request doesn't return any results.

I encountered this problem while refactoring the view-controller components from my `NSPersistentDocument` subclass to a new `NSWindowController` subclass. I used to handle this initialization in `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:`, but that isn't called anymore.

If I move the code from `-init` to `-makeWindowControllers` I get the results I expect. Is `-makeWindowControllers` really the right place to prepare content like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the responses I've gotten I think I'm doing the right thing, so here's my answer to my own question.

**If you're using the Core Data stack provided by NSPersistentDocument, you can not use Core Data in `-init`.**

Instead, you should:

1. Put the document-initialization code directly in `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` – or if you use a custom NSWindowController subclass, in `-makeWindowControllers`.
2. You may also abstract the document-initialization code into a helper method with some unique name like `-setUpDocument`, and call that method from `-makeWindowControllers`/`-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` instead.

If you're using a plain NSDocument, or you're setting up the Core Data stack on your own, you can set up the document model in `-init`.

Comment: thanks, that's what i search for, the only thing you should be awared of is you can not save the context. Anyway this is covered by the NSDocument/NSPersistentDocument.

Comment: What do you mean – that you can't save the context in -makeWindowControllers?

Comment: don't call `save` on the instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: What happens when you do?

Comment: I get "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation." If I place e.g. `[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];` in `makeWindowControllers` (under the condition there is something to save :) ). But again, I think this is ok, only the user or autosave should trigger save. I just had the issue/bug and I thought I can mention it.

Answer (score 2):

From this question and your related question about NSArrayControllers, I'm gathering that you're doing something like this:

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers
{
    MyWindowController* wc = [[[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: [self windowNibName]] autorelease];
    [self addWindowController: wc];
}
```

When you do this, `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` won't be called, because the NSDocument object isn't the Nib's owner if you init that way. If you look at `NSDocument.h` you'll see the following comment (see added emphasis):

```
/* Create the user interface for this document, but don't show it yet. The
default implementation of this method invokes [self windowNibName],
creates a new window controller using the resulting nib name (if it is
not nil), **specifying this document as the nib file's owner**, and then
invokes [self addWindowController:theNewWindowController] to attach it.
You can override this method to use a custom subclass of
NSWindowController or to create more than one window controller right
away. NSDocumentController invokes this method when creating or opening
new documents.
*/
- (void)makeWindowControllers;
```

If you, instead, do this:

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers
{
    MyWindowController* wc = [[[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: [self windowNibName] owner: self] autorelease];
    [self addWindowController: wc];
}
```

I believe you'll find that `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` is called again. That may not help you, if you have a good reason for that Nib's owner to not be the NSDocument, but that's why `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` isn't being called, and what you can do to get that behavior back.  That's almost certainly a better place to be doing fetches than in init, which likely happens before all the necessary CoreData support stuff is in place.  So that's one option.

Comment: You're exactly right that I'm creating window controllers using code like your sample. I'm also creating a print view which the document owns (so I can print without creating a window), and fetching data from the MOC. It works fine, it just feels strange. You're absolutely right that I shouldn't do the initialization in `-init` – Core Data doesn't work yet (despite the MOC being instantiated).

Comment: Changing the nib owner as you suggest would result in `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` being called, but ultimately it's only different from doing the initialization directly in `-makeWindowControllers`, because it happens later. (Which doesn't seem to my advantage either – I'd rather set up the document completely, then create the window controller.)

Comment: Making the model-controller (NSPersistentDocument) the nib owner seems to undo the benefit of separating out the view-controller (NSWindowController) in the first place. I would have to add outlets to the 'document' for view-related objects constructed in the nib (date formatters, array controllers, accessory windows, and their view controllers) even though they only concern the window controller.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. It helps me feel confident that given the current API, I've got this set up the best way I can.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is not called from init that is because your document is being initialized elsewhere such as `initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:`, `initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:`, `initWithType:error:` or `initWithCoder:` `makeWindowControllers` is not for setting up your data. Try implementing all of the above initializers and log to see which is getting called.

Comment: The code gets called. The question isn't about that. It's about ''fetch requests not returning results'' in `-init`.

Comment: Well I'm sorry I was wrong. (Your original post was not clear about this). This is no reason to downvote, though.

Comment: My question was, "Is -makeWindowControllers the best place to initialize an NSPersistentDocument?" which I thought *was* clear in my original post. I suppose you're right; maybe it wasn't as clear as I thought. Sorry. If you edit your post I'll remove the vote.